# Duplicate key entry when updating object

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `Product` object that has multiple `Shop` objects because a shop can offer the same product at different prices / conditions.

I have an edit view for the products that lists the shops where the product is available.

When I make adjustments to the shops of the product eg. price; I get the error that the shop already exists in the database. I know the product exists, but I need the data to be updated.

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

```
    public function update(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        $product = Product::with('shops', 'type')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
       [... snip ...]

        $i = 0;
        foreach($product->shops as $shop) {
            $shop = request('shop');
            $product->shops()->attach($product->id, [
              'shop_id' => $shop[$i]['id'],
              'price' => $shop[$i]['price'],
              'url' => $shop[$i]['url']
            ]);
            $i++;
        }

        $product->save();

      return redirect('/'.$slug)->with('success', 'Product has been updated');
    }
```

`$product->update();` yields the same result.

EDIT:

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $appends = ['lowest_price'];

    public function shops(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shop')->withPivot('price','url');
    }

    public function type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Type');
    }

    public function getLowestPriceAttribute()
    {
        $lowest_price = NULL;
        foreach($this->shops as $shop) {
            if(is_null($lowest_price)) { 
                $lowest_price = (double)$shop->pivot->price;
            }

            if($lowest_price > (double)$shop->pivot->price) {
                $lowest_price = (double)$shop->pivot->price;
            }
        }
        return $lowest_price;
    }

}
```

**Shop.php**

```
class Shop extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**Shop migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('logo');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        [... snip ...]
    }
```

EDIT2:

More info about the error:

```
 Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000)
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `product_shop` (`price`, `product_id`, `shop_id`, `url`) values (500.00, 1, 1, http://test.com))
```

```
'CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `make` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `video` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer_specs` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `top_speed` decimal(8,1) NOT NULL,
  `range` decimal(8,1) NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(8,1) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lowest_price` decimal(8,1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `products_slug_unique` (`slug`),
  KEY `products_type_id_index` (`type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

```
'CREATE TABLE `product_shop` (
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `url` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`shop_id`),
  KEY `product_shop_product_id_index` (`product_id`),
  KEY `product_shop_shop_id_index` (`shop_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_shop_product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `product_shop_shop_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`shop_id`) REFERENCES `shops` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

```
'CREATE TABLE `shops` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

Edit3:
If I click the update button, I get the error even if I didn't change anything
[image]

Comment: *"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'"* educated guess it feels like a missing `AUTO_INCREMENT` option on the `PRIMARY KEY` column in your table .. -> `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`

Comment: .. also it would help if you show the `Product` and `Shop ? `  class code..

Comment: @RaymondNijland AI is enabled for the ID of both Product and Shop. The code has been added.

Comment: You sure that `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'` is triggerd on `$product->save();` and not before ? >..   Also it would help if you add a `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` for those Product and Shop classes aswell so we know how the tables looks like in MySQL..   And the generated SQL which `$product->save();` generates so we know that happens..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, I am possitive it happens at `$product->save();`. Code added aswel.

Comment: The error is not thrown at `save()` but on `attach()`, the problem is that you are trying to attach a shop that already is attached to the product. Does `request('shop')` contain all shops that are attached and the new ones that should be attached?

Comment: @Remul Is there a way to avoid the error and update instead of attach?

Comment: If you always provide all shops e.g. all that are already attached and the new ones that should be attached you can use [sync()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)  instead of `attach()`, it will detach all existing shops and then reattach the ones you supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add another product-to-shop relation with the same keys, that's why you are seeing the index violation.

Instead of using `attach`, you can use `sync`:

```
$product->shops()->sync(
    [
        $shop[$i]['id'] => [
            'price' => $shop[$i]['price'],
            'url' => $shop[$i]['url']
        ]
    ], false);
```

The important part is the second parameter, which disabled `detaching` the other related items.
You could also use `syncWithoutDetaching`.

For details see:

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

[Api](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_sync)

Comment: `toggle()` should also work in this case as the `product_shop` table is a many-to-many relation.. -> *"Toggling Associations The many-to-many relationship also provides a toggle method which "toggles" the attachment status of the given IDs. If the given ID is currently attached, it will be detached. Likewise, if it is currently detached, it will be attached:"*

Comment: I don't think so - in the current case, the pivot columns should be updated. This means, if a n-m relation already exists, it should be updated, if it doesn't exist, it should be created. With toggle, it would probably handle an update as detaching, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: You might be right not sure about it as i didn't program in laravel for years now..

Comment: @MatthiasS I have tried `sync()` and `syncWithoutDetaching` but now I get an error on the second shop: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: update `product_shop` set `shop_id` = 2, `price` = 550.00, `url` = http://google.be where `product_id` = 1 and `shop_id` in (1))`... I also added a picture to the question

Comment: I edited my answer. You are already using `$product` so laravel automatically knows which product_id to use. What you need to supply as the ID is therefore the `shop_id`. I edited the code snippet to reflect that.

Comment: @MatthiasS Updating the existing shops works great now, but when I add a new shop it is part of the $request, but not saved.

Comment: Hm, weird. Sync should also create new items. I tested it locally and it does indeed add new keys if they are not present. So can't really say why it is not working now...

Comment: @MatthiasS I'll keep working on it. Thanks for all your help! I've accepted your answer.